# HTML5 - How to target a new page and start downloading with the 'Your download has started'

Tags: html

I am trying to open a new page when clicked on a button which will show 'Your Download has started' (or something like that) and start the downloading.
HTML5 doesn't support 'target'. Is there an analogous for this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use an **anchor element()** instead of button element and give it a shape like a button. If you are using bootstrap then you can do like below:

```
<a href="new-page.html" class="btn btn-primary">Download</a>
```

This way you don't have to use target attribute.

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="example.html" download onclick="window.open(this.href,'_blank');return true;">
  click me to download
</a>
```

try